# A program to simulate the roll of a dice turn-wise

Tags: python-3.x

I wrote a program to simulate the roll of a dice turn-wise. However after running the program it always displays none after every line. Can someone help me out ?

```
import random

#Function That Simulates Dice Roll

def dice_roll():

    while True:

        print()
        question = (input(print("Do you want to roll the dice ? (Y/N)")))
        print()

        if question == 'Y' or question == 'y':

            name = input(print("Enter your name"))
            print()
            print(name + ":")
            print()
            num = random.randint(1, 7)

            print("The Dice rolls and The number is " + " " + str(num))

        elif question == 'N' or question == 'n':

            print("OK")
            print("Exiting The Program")
            print("Have a nice day :-)")
            break

#Above Function Gets Called

dice_roll()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put `print` inside your `input` call.

```
question = (input(print("Do you want to roll the dice ? (Y/N)")))
```

What you're doing here is calling `print` (which prints your message), and passing print's return value (which is `None`) to `input`, which uses it as a prompt for the input. So you get `None` printed each time you ask for input.

If you have

```
question = input("Do you want to roll the dice ? (Y/N)")
```

that will be sufficient.